# In the command tar –cvjf foo.tbz a b c, what are a, b, and c?

Tags: tar, documentation

I know these aren't extra flags to be passed to the tar command, aren't they just files names to be added to the archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the files/directories which the `tar` command should include in the new created `foo.tbz` tarball.

tar flags:

- `-c` Create a new tarball
- `-v` verbose
- `-j` use bzip2 compression
- `-f foo.tbz` Use foo.tbz as (here output) file

---

- `a b c` further arguments: file names/directory names which tar should include in the new tarball.

Answer (score 0):

It's common that, when using compression tools, the arguments after the flags and the file to be created are the files to include or add to the newly created file.  In this case, `a`, `b`, and `c` are the files to include in your newly created file `foo.tbz`.  The same happens when using other tools besides `tar`, like `zip`.

Comment: `gzip` takes multiple names on the commandline as more files to compress, not as something to include or add.

Comment: You are correct - missed that, thanks!  Fixing right away...

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're unfamiliar with a command line tool, it's helpful to take a look a the man page.

*excerpt - man tar*

```
SYNOPSIS
       tar [OPTION...] [FILE]...
```

The synopsis, which most commands will have, shows that `a`, `b`, and `c` would be the files/directories in this example.